# How to fix AWS Cli issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am new to Amazon Web Services. I am trying to use the CLI that i have configured on my instance. 
I am trying to use many commands, but getting the following **Error**:

```
aws glacier create-vault --vault-name my-vault --account-id -"Invalid endpoint: https://glacier.US East (N. Virginia).amazonaws.com
```

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 27):

```
Invalid endpoint: https://glacier.US East (N. Virginia).amazonaws.com
```

From the error message, it looks like you have specified an invalid region **US East (N. Virginia)** in your CLI configuration. Instead specify **us-east-1**. Check your `~/.aws/config` or environment vars or wherever you are setting the region. Set your region to:

```
region=us-east-1
```

Comment: Note that [environment variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html) override options set under `~/.aws` (by `aws configure`, etc.), so if `$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` is set, make sure it's set correctly.

Comment: You can also re-run `aws configure` and for the Default region name provide a string that matches the format [country]-[region]-[number]. For example: "us-east-1" without quotes.

Answer (score 2):

On **C:\Users\username\.aws\config**, Change your region from *US East (N. Virginia)* to

> [default]
>
> region = us-east-1

Answer (score 1):

Their is problem in your End-point please find your respective [End points](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

**Delete your .aws file and add aws configuration again.**
Default path of .aws will be under /Users//.aws
    1. rm -rf /Users//.aws
    2. aws configure

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar kind of issue.

1. Please change your default region to us-east-1 by running the `aws configure` command.
2. You probably might forgot to switch to root user while access your EC2 instance from SSH console.

Please run the command `sudo su` to switch to root user.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a lot of credentials already configured that is making the terminal confused. I have a very short fix to this. Go to your aws hidden folder which you can find with [shift + command + .] when on your finders folder (if you are using MAC).  Open the aws hidden file and clear all the credential and config. This will return your "aws configure" to default and that will resolve the error.